# Python Crash Course, chapter 19, registration

Tags: python, django

I am a noob, currently on the chapter 19 of this book by No Starch Press. Try to build a registration option in my blog but sadly the version I have of the book is not updated on the latest version of Django. I already checked for support on other sites but I am really lost since all the info I get are related to different versions of Django .
When I try to run the server I get an error about the line

```
 from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationFormfrom django.shortcuts import render
```

the function I wrote in the views section of the app is..

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationFormfrom django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(request):
    """Register a new user."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Display blank registration form.   
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        # Process completed form.
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
    
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            # Log the user in and then redirect to home page.
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('learning_logs:index')

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

for the url on the site I wrote...

```
"""Defines URL patterns for users"""

from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    # Include default auth urls.
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # Registration page.
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Comment: I think it should be `from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationFormfrom <add a new line here> from django.shortcuts import render`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem. A little embarrassing hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the error is due to a typo. So, instead of doing this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationFormfrom django.shortcuts import render
```

Try this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationFormfrom
from django.shortcuts import render
```

Comment: hehe well that's embarrassing, thank you so much. Yes that was the problem and yes I spend 5 hours on it. Thanks